# How to pause code between the display of 2 alerts

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, pause

I have some iOS code where I need to be able to display 2 back to back alerts.  When the user clicks "ok" on the first alert then I need to display the second alert.  Because displaying an alert does not "pause" the code, my second alert tries to display at almost the same time as my first alert and things break (second alert does not show up).

What I need is a way to pause the code while displaying the first alert.  Once the user clicks "ok" on the first alert then it can display the second alert.

What is the proper way to wait for first alert to finish before moving on to the second alert?

Here is my full code in case it helps.  Each alert is triggered by a condition.  If both conditions are true then I hit the back to back alert issue I have described.

```
    UIAlertController* alert;
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction;
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if(status != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:@"Reminder will not work unless you enable 'Always' location."
                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];


        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }


    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
    if(settings.types==0) {
        alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:@"Reminder will not work unless you enable notifications."
                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Adding a follow up comment now that my code is working.  From what I gather there is no way to "pause" the code to wait for the user to hit OK on an alert.  I tried that at one point - setting a flag when user hits OK and waiting for that flag to be set before moving on.  This wait loop crashed my UI.  The final solution was to check if 2 alerts needs to be displayed and if that is the case then displaying the second alert inside a block of code passed into the first alert (solution 1 below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is but the second alert in the handler for the first:

```
UIAlertController* alert;
UIAlertAction* defaultAction;
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if(status != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
    alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                message:@"Reminder will not work unless you enable 'Always' location."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

        if(settings.types==0) {

            inner_alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                message:@"Reminder will not work unless you enable notifications."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            inner_defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

            [inner_alert addAction:inner_defaultAction];
            [self presentViewController:inner_alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];


    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This way when you hit "Ok" it will then call the code for the second alert.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It took me a while to realize you were putting the second alert in a block that gets passed into the first alert.  What I need, though, is a clean way to handle showing alert A, alert B, or both alert A and B.  I would need to add more code for handling alert B in the case where alert A is not required. I suppose I could do this.

Comment: @Morocco5, yes you would have to include a conditional to check when to call it. This is just how you'd do two alerts at a time. If this answers your question please mark it as correct and up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable in the @interface and set it to 0 in viewDidLoad

```
@interface ViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic) int number;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.number = 0;

}
```

Then create function to show alert and call other alert by switch(self.number) or you can call showAlert itself again.

```
    - (void) showAlert {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertController WithTitle:@"ALERT" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        switch (self.number) {
            case 0:
            self.number = 1;                
            [self secondAlert]; // other alert function
                break;
            case 1:
            [self thirdAlert];
            default:
            break;
            }
    }];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            }];

    [alert addAction:okAction];
    [alert addAction:cancelAction];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```